# how to solve run time error or Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException?

Tags: objective-c

I am a beginner with iPhone development. I have used scrollview with an array of images but in that run time error like Terminating app due to uncaught exception: `NSInvalidArgumentException`, reason: `-[UIView setContentSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [self.view addSubview:imagedisplay];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

    [(UIScrollView*)self.view setContentSize:[imagedisplay size]];

    [(UIScrollView*)self.view setMaximumZoomScale:5.0];
}

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    return imagedisplay;

}
```

Give any suggestions and source code which applies.

Comment: Can you post your declaration and initialization of imagedisplay?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem line is:

```
[(UIScrollView*)self.view setContentSize:[imagedisplay size]];
```

It's saying that **`self.view`** does not contain the method `ContentSize` where **self** is a `UIView` and not a `UIScrolLView`.